# Plugin [id: 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal.onesignal-gradle-plugin'] was not found

Tags: android, gradle

Plugin [id: 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal.onesignal-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
}
....
dependencies {

     ...
     implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.2.0'
}
```

I am using android studio Arctic 2020.3.1 .gradle 7.0.2

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: According to https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin here must be
  id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'  
instead 
  id 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

Answer (score 2):

Correct way of adding OneSignal dependency and plugins according to their API

**build.gradle (Project: name)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
}
```

And finally in dependecies section

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
}
```